# Impossible to avoid 'using filesort' in a very simple query with order

Tags: mysql, using, explain, filesort

I'm trying to create a select query but mysql always use "using filesort" in extra when I use explain query.

I try with the most simple query, but the problem doesn't disappear.
The structure of my table 'Partidas' is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Partidas` (
  `IdUsuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IdPartida` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `TipoPartida` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Facil` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Normal` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Dificil` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `FchPartida` date NOT NULL,
  `PuntosPartida` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `IdPartidaTemp` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `ComplPers` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `SoloMulti` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdUsuario`,`IdPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_RECORDS` (`TipoPartida`,`FchPartida`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_ORDEN2` (`FchPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_COMPLPERS` (`ComplPers`,`FchPartida`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_SOLOMULTI` (`SoloMulti`,`FchPartida`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_DIFICULTAD` (`Facil`,`Normal`,`Dificil`,`SoloMulti`,`FchPartida`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_COMPMULTI` (`ComplPers`,`SoloMulti`,`FchPartida`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_COMPLPERS_SIMPLE` (`ComplPers`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_SOLOMULTI_SIMPLE` (`SoloMulti`,`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_FECHA` (`FchPartida`),
  KEY `IX_PARTIDAS_PUNTOS` (`PuntosPartida`),
  KEY `PRUEBA_PARTIDAS` (`PuntosPartida`,`TipoPartida`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The table has about 1000-5000 rows (really little data), but always use using filesort. The query I'm using for test is:

```
explain select *
from Partidas
order by PuntosPartida
limit 0, 50;
```

and the result is:

```
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Partidas           | ALL   | NULL          | NULL      | NULL    |NULL  | 1041 | Using filesort |
```

but if in the query I change the limit, for example, limit 0,5; then the result changes too

```
| id | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key                | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Partidas           | index | NULL          | IX_PARTIDAS_PUNTOS | 3       |NULL  |  5   |             |
```

In mysql configuration, the variables of buffer and sort are:

```
-myisam sort buffer size: 2MB
-sort buffer size: 2MB
-key buffer size: 1GB
```

but I try to change these values (increasing it until 8MB) and the result is the same

Thank you for help

Comment: there is no "using filesort" in the explain result you showed us

Comment: You can try with `USE INDEX (IX_PARTIDAS_PUNTOS)` if you are sure that for this query the index will be faster. Or try to run `ANALYZE TABLE Partidas` to recalculate index statistics. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: this concrete query is very fast, but I'm worried because I have the same problem in other tables bigger than this, and they are slow and I think the problem is the using filesort and using temporary, and I wanted soved first the most simple query

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is the query optimizer doing its job. [This article here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/) shows that "the optimizer preferred a full table scan, and it did not even consider scanning the index as a relevant choice (possible_keys: NULL)"

You can force it to use an index but the execution time may be slower (as mentioned in the article as well).

```
select *
from Partidas FORCE INDEX(IX_PARTIDAS_PUNTOS)
order by PuntosPartida
limit 0, 50;
```

You can also [read more here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/how-to-avoid-table-scan.html) on how to avoid table scans ("using filesort")